# Blank Project in Parse iOS SDK

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm a totally newbie to iOS development (you can tell from my username!), I just downloaded IOS SDK Blank Project for Parse from this address:

https://www.parse.com/docs/downloads

Inside the "ParseStarterProject-Swift" I double clicked and opened the "ParseStarterProject-Swift.xcodeproj" file, but after it opens in XCode, at the tree project navigator tree on the lefthand side, it is greyed out and non of the related files and folders show up under the tree. Please see the picture. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks a lot for your kind help!
[Parse iOS Blank Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNDPw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hum kinda strange... I just opened the project successfully.
I am using Xcode 7.0.1 and I downloaded Blank Project v1.9.0...
Can you check the versions you're using?

Another thing I could imagine - as the xcode project is marked red, meaning the file cannot be found - would be that your disk partition is set to case sensitive whereas the filename defined in the project tree could have a different case. You should localise the file and ensure the case corresponds to what you can see in the right pane Identity and Type > Full Path... but that is just a guess.

Comment: Thanks Alde, my xcode is 6.1 and iOS is 10.9. I created a "Workspace" using xcode and then right-clicked on the tree and added the xcode project file and then the full tree was showing. But the problem with that was, I guess, the autocomplete feature wasn't working in the code files such as Appdelegat. For example, when I wanted to create a twitter log-in, it didn't recognize PFTwitterUtils and I was getting an error. I'm updating my xcode and macbook OS and will update here later..., thanks